# Probability distribution and expectated number of factors shared by two dice with 12 sides?

Tags: probability, dice

I've already seen [You roll two dice. What is the probability of the event that they have no common factor greater than unity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107341) but I'm looking into a similar but distinct problem, one I don't even know how to approach besides simply enumerating all possible results. Ideally I'd like to 'learn how to fish' instead of just be given fish.

As a concrete example, if the two 12-sided dice come up 4 and 12, they share ${1,2,4}$ as factors - so they would 'score' 3. The dice 7 and 7 would share ${1,7}$ (scoring 2) and two lots of 12 would share ${1,2,3,4,6,12}$ (scoring 6).

Is it easy to work out a probability distribution for this problem? Or is it not mathematically possible and I need to manually work out all 144 combinations?

Comment: Questions should be self contained.  It's not clear what you are asking here...nor is it clear what it means to "share" $1,2,2$.

Comment: @lulu We have $4=1\times 2\times 2$ and $12=1\times 2\times 2\times 3$. The $1,2,2$ are the shared factors with repetition.

Comment: @user469053  The OP ought to clarify.  Is the question just "find the probability that the gcd is $1$"?  Is it "find the probability that the gcd is $d$ for any given $d$"?    In any case, the numbers are small enough to just enumerate.

Comment: @lulu I believe OP's question is quite clear. In their example, three factors are shared. OP is asking about the distribution of the number of factors which are shared. 

OP is clearly not asking what is the probability that the gcd is 1, because that is the "similar but distinct" problem that they explicitly link to.

Comment: "In any case, the numbers are small enough to just enumerate." OP specifically asks for a way to approach the problem **besides** simply enumerating.

Comment: Just because a question is easy to ask does not make it easy to answer with pen-and-paper methods.  I agree with brute force here.

Comment: If the *only* question were asking for the *expected number of factors* and not the probability distribution... then linearity of expectation is (*as usual*) incredibly powerful here.  Letting $X$ be the total number of factors, note that $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_{12}$ where $X_i$ is the probability that both have $i$ as a factor, and so $E[X]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_{12}]$

Comment: @JMoravitz $X_i$ should be the indicator, not the probability. I do not think you are quite answering what OP is asking, because they said $4$ and $12$ share common factors $1,2,2$. OP did not say they share $4$. So I suspect we are looking for $1$ and prime factors with repetition.

Comment: I rather strongly suspect that the OP made a mistake and "1,2,2"' was a typo when they meant to say "1,2,4"...  People make typos.  Seeing past the typos and reading the real question is an important skill here.  In any event, the OP could/should clarify for the case of 6,12 if the "shared common factors" should be 1,2,3,6 or just 1,2,3... or the case of 12,12 if its 1,2,3,4,6,12 or if its 1,2,2,3.  Again, this is a moot point since OP also asks for the probability distribution, we're not easily able to avoid brute force.  *Some* simplification is possible, but not much.

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with JMoravitz' last comment.  On the other hand, I also think that the last comment of user469053 is well taken.  As a matter of policy, I don't feel that a MathSE reviewer should attempt to provide an *answer* until the original poster digests these comments and adds clarification directly into their posting.  That is, I feel that MathSE reviewers should not endorse the risk of *trying to hit a moving target*.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the expected number of factors, we can calculate this easily without bothering to look at the probability distribution.

Letting $X$ be the random variable counting the total number of factors shared, and letting $X_i$ be the indicator random variable corresponding to whether $i$ is a factor of both the first and second die, we can see that $X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{12}$ and thanks to the linearity of expectation that $E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{12}]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_{12}]$, this despite any possible dependence between these.

Now, $E[X_i]=\Pr(X_i=1)$ is simply going to be equal to the probability that $i$ is a factor of each die result, and will be equal to $\frac{k}{12^2}$ where $k$ is the number of integer multiples of $i$ in the range $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$

We get then a calculation of:

$$E[X] = \dfrac{12^2+6^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2}{12^2}$$

$$ = \dfrac{219}{144}= 1.5208\overline{3}$$

Actually finding the probability distribution for the number of factors however will be highly tedious brute force.  For instance, to find those pairs of numbers in increasing order with two shared factors would be (2,2),(2,4),(2,6),(2,8),(2,10),(2,12),(3,3),(3,6),(3,9),(3,12),(4,6),(4,10),(5,5),(5,10),(6,8),(6,10),(7,7),(8,10),(9,12),...
and take the count of all of these (*and their reverses*) and divide by $12^2$ to find the probability.

It can be done, but to reemphasize... if all we were wanting was to find the expected value then *we don't have to do this!*  It is a waste of time and effort.